# connections em aplicação web

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jsf, jdbc, conexão

Estou a criar um projeto J2EE, jsf. Têm vários beans e controller, e os beans acedem a Base de dados. Estou com dúvidas como gerir as connection para a base de dados, neste momento tenho só uma connection, mas não faz sentido. Pensei numa pool que é lançado por cada thread (cada cliente) mas não sei como gerir essa pool. Alguma dica como gerir as connection numa aplicação web ?

O que está feito agora é cada query que preciso de fazer a BD faço:

```
connection.openDBConnection();
ps = conn.getConnection( ).prepareStatement( Constants.updateValue );
....
connection.closeDBConnection();
```

Não gosto da ideia de criar uma ligação por query ou por um conjunto de queries. 
Obrigado

Comment: mostre seu código para uma melhor análise

Comment: comentario editado

Comment: O mais comum no Java EE é deixar a gestão de conexão por conta do servidor de aplicativos, deixando o container injetar o contexto de acesso ao banco (ou mesmo obtê-lo programaticamente) em vez de criar, abrir e fechar conexão explicitamente. Você pode escrever todo o código para fazer esta gestão, mas fazê-lo de maneira segura e com performance dá trabalho e exige bastante conhecimento. Este artigo parece um bom começo (não achei nada em português): http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/configuring-jndi-datasource-for-database-connection-pooling-in-tomcat. E use Java 7 ou 8, e não o 2!